# Control ggplot2 facet height independently from number of row facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

### Problem

[ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org)/[knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) forces plots (in LaTeX) to have the default aspect ratio. Two Plots which have different number of facets result in plots with facet heights being different. This is not nice.

[image: Example for problem]

*I was looking for a solution which controls the ggplot2 facet height independently from the number of row facets.*

**Edited Sept. 9th:**
*The solution should work within one chunk as both plots are in one chunk (as in the example code). So tweaking knitr's figure related chunk options is not viable, as the chunk option applies to both plots equally.*

### Solution - but having problems

Putting each plot into a [gridExtra](http://code.google.com/p/gridextra/) box and scaling it's height with the number of facets, results in facet heights which are no longer different: nicer but not perfect.

- Plots appear on the page with too much margin, even there's remaining text below so plots shall move more closer.
- Seems plots manipulated by this get cropped.

**Is there a smarter and problem-free solution which controls the ggplot2 facet height independently from the number of row facets?**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

<<setup, results='asis', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

### Generate two data frames

# Data frame with 2 classes
db.small = data.frame (
  class = as.factor(c(rep("A", 12), rep("B", 12))),
  month = as.factor(rep(1:12, 2)),
  value = runif(2*12, 0, 100)
  )

# Data frame with 5 classes
db.large = data.frame (
  class = as.factor(c(rep("A", 12), rep("B", 12), rep("C", 12), rep("C", 12), rep("D", 12))),
  month = as.factor(rep(1:12, 5)),
  value = runif(5*12, 0, 100)
)

# Generate plots
plot1 = ggplot(db.small, aes(month, value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(class ~ .) + ylim(c(0, 100))
plot2 = ggplot(db.large, aes(month, value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(class ~ .) + ylim(c(0, 100))
@

\section{Before: Native plots without modification}
Ggplot2/knitr forces both plots to have the default aspect ratio. As both plots have different number of facets the result is that the facet heights are different. This is not nice.

<<before, results='asis', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, out.width="0.6\\linewidth">>=
print(plot1)
print(plot2)
@

\pagebreak
\section{After: Plots with modification}
Putting each plot into a gridExtra box and scaling it's height with the number of facets, results in facet heights which are no longer different: nicer but not perfect, see problems below.

<<After, results='asis', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, out.width="0.6\\linewidth">>=
# Calculate number of facets for the two plots
db.small.numberfacets = length(unique(db.small$class))
db.large.numberfacets = length(unique(db.large$class))

# Define heights for modification of plots
facet.height = 4
other.height = 2

plot1 = plot1 + theme( plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
plot2 = plot2 + theme( plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))

# Put plots inside a gridExtra box and change height plots
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(plot1, heights=unit(db.small.numberfacets*facet.height+other.height, "cm")), nrow=1)
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(plot2, heights=unit(db.large.numberfacets*facet.height+other.height, "cm")), nrow=1)
@


2 Problems:
\begin{itemize}
\item Plots appear on the page with too much margin, even there's remaining text below so plots shall move more closer.
\item Seems the second plot is cropped, see the x-axis label.
\end{itemize}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```

pdf Output:
[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Answer (score 4):

Do you know that knitr [chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) can take arbitrary R expressions? The [example 40](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/040-grid-table.Rnw) shows how you can calculate `fig.width` and `fig.height` dynamically.

For your case, you can assign a value to `fig.height` according to the number of levels in the factor variable for faceting. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<setup>>=
library(ggplot2)
calc_height = function(f) length(levels(f))
p = ggplot(diamonds, aes(color)) + geom_bar()
@

<<test-a, fig.width=7, fig.height=calc_height(diamonds$cut)>>==
p + facet_grid(cut ~ .)
@

<<test-b, fig.width=7, fig.height=calc_height(diamonds$clarity)>>==
p + facet_grid(clarity ~ .)
@

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this chunk option. As I have the two plots in one chunk (it's part of a loop) the chunk option seems not applicable. I need a solution which controls the facet height for each plot even if they belong to the same chunk.

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify, that the solution should also work for two plot being part of one and the same knitr chunk. Thanks.

Comment: @user2030503 I see. I just have not completely decided how to vectorize `fig.width` and `fig.height`: now they are vectorized according to `dev`, but I can also change the design and let them vectorize according to plots.

Comment: That's great news. Can you post a code snippet how it looks like to set fig.height as vectorized chunk option?

Comment: @user2030503 e.g. `dev=c('pdf', 'png'), fig.height=c(7, 5)`, then the pdf device uses 7, and png uses 5 on the same plot; in your case, you need the fig.height vector to be mapped to plots in the same chunk instead of devices, which is not the way `fig.height` is currently implemented